# Read file that is used by another process

Tags: c#, file, .net

Is there ability to read file that is used by another process?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048225/how-do-i-open-a-file-that-is-opened-in-another-application

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778779/files-on-multiple-processes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the process holds an exclusive lock on the file then no. If the process holds a shared lock, you can read it.

Comment: if a process holds a hared lock, it's possibleto read file like this:
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\myfile.xls", 
       FileMode.Open, 
       FileAccess.Read, 
       FileShare.ReadWrite))
{...}

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the files you want to access, have a look at [Volume Shadow Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the other process opened the file (i.e., is it locked).
Bear in mind that reading a file while it is being changed by another process may yield unexpected results.