# C#: silent access to opened file

Tags: c#, file, file-io, readonly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read file which is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709104/read-file-which-is-in-use)

I have a such situation/question:

1. One txt file opened at present time by some program. This program writes some log stuff into file.
2. My C# program should open that file in read-only mode but access should be silent and should not block access to file.

What C# function(s) could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Say "shhhhhhhhh"

Comment: `-1` for overlooking dozen of duplicates ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1048225/944681), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1158100/944681), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3709104/944681), ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass the appropriate parameters to the `File.Open()` method:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("path", 
   FileMode.Open, 
   FileAccess.Read, 
   FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    // You can read, they (logger) can write
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileShare flag allows to open an opened file.